# undefined behaviour of srand and rand

Tags: c, linux

I am trying to generate random number using `srand` and `rand`. Here I want to generate specific number of digit. When I am executing my program at some time if I ask to generate 5 digit number number it is not giving me desired output.

My code is

```
for(k=0;k<n;k++)
    {
            temp = temp*10;
    }
    srand(time(NULL));
    i = rand()%temp;
    printf("%d\n",i);
    k = 0;
    temp = n;
    while(i != 0)
    {
            arr1[n+k] = i%10;
            i = i/10;
            n--;
    }
```

Output

```
Number of digits you want : 5
2031
while loop 1
while loop 3
while loop 0
while loop 2
N is 1
arr1[1] = 10651312
arr1[2] = 2
arr1[3] = 0
arr1[4] = 3
arr1[5] = 1
```

tell me where is the problem for getting desired number of digits.

`Edit`
I run that code around 100 times and out of those four time it is not working, rest is fine...

Comment: ..?? output doesn't belongs to given code.

Comment: Shouldn't your loop be on the size of the array, not until you exhaust the random number? If the top digit is zero it won't initialise that part of the array and you'd be left with random garbage.

Comment: @Dayalrai... It`s same output... I just provide snippet...

Comment: @Rup...code is working fine but out of 100 times it is producing such behaviour...

Answer (score 2):

The problem is you're looping on the size of the random number you've generated and not the size of the array. In your example you want five digits but your code has generated a four digit number, 2031. This means that in the iteration of your bottom loop

- ... n = 2, i = 2: store a[2] = 2, i = 0
- ... n = 1, i = 0: loop condition failed, a[1] never set

which leaves random garbage in a[1]. If your random number did in fact contain 5 digits, not 4, then it would have completed the loop correctly.

Instead you want to loop over n

```
for(int j = n; j > 0; --j)
{
    arr1[n+j] = i%10;
    i = i/10;
}
```

Note that this is still using the array as 1-based, whereas in c arrays are 0-based, i.e. they start at element 0, i.e. in order to use arr1[5] you need to have malloced or declared 6 array elements or 6*sizeof(int) bytes. Also note that you should use better variable names than `temp`, and there's no benefit to reusing the variable: your compiler will automatically reuse registers and sort that out for you.

Comment: @Rup... If this is the problem then 96 times I got perfect result...I think if this is the problem then it should not work anytime...

Comment: I think this is definitely a problem. This will happen when the top digit or digits of the generated random number is 0, i.e. it should still work 9/10 times.

Comment: Alternatively you could zero the array beforehand (or calloc it if you're allocating it) and then your code world work fine as-is.

Comment: @Rup... I tried as you suggested...But again when I want to generate 6 digit number it is giving me 5 digits only

Comment: I am again having problem here...That array length is user defined so compiler producing error.. can not zero array beforehand.

Answer (score 2):

There are several problems here.

First, call srand() once before actually producing random numbers.

Second, your method taking the returned number modulo some power of 10 will, of course, also return numbers that are lower. For example, n%100000 could be anything from 0 to 99999.

Comment: @Ingo... Sorry I didnt get your answer... If I want any number between 0 to 99999 what should be another approach.

Comment: You said you wanted 5 digit numbers. But you get also 4 digit, 3 digit, 2 digit and single digit ones.

Comment: @Ingo... Number of digits are user defined, not fixed.

Comment: How does that matter? Every time you want to generate n digit numbers with your method, you may get also all numbers with less digits. See @Chrono Kitsunes answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
n = rand() % (largest - smallest + 1) + smallest;
```

If you want a 5 digit number, what is the smallest 5 digit number? Do the same for the largest number. That can be used for any number range with no need to fill an array or anything.

Now you just need to figure out how to generate the largest and smallest values for the number of digits specified.

Happy coding!

Comment: He's already doing that, in his `i = rand()%temp;` line. The problem (I think) is that he has to break it into individual digits too.

Comment: `rand()%temp` will get a value between 0 and temp, not including temp. If you get 0, no matter how you break it up, it is still 0. You could get 2. The logic here is that there is no account for such a case. If you want a 5 digit number, you must add at least a 5 digit number in case `rand()%temp` turns out to be 0. But you can't go over 5 digits either, so you need a maximum value that expresses that. For example, `rand()%90 + 10` would give me a 2 digit number: 0+10=10, and 89+10=99. The formula works, but if you don't understand it, it can't help you. :-p

Comment: @ChronoKitsune... Thanks for your support. But when user ask to produce 5 digit value it will produce in the range of 10000 to 99999, not only zero. Zero will come only in one condition when user wants only one digit number so that range will be 0 to 9....

Comment: That is what you want, yes, but if temp is 10000 and rand() gives you 30000, `rand()%temp` will be 0 because 30000%10000==0. This is why you need to add a number to `rand()%temp`. That way you get a 5 digit number still instead of something like 0 or 2031 or whatever. You need to add a value or it won't do what you want.